# What is difference between creating a file with fopen and generating file with headers

Tags: php, excel

**One Way**
am creating an xls with fopen("test.xls") .

Using fwrite i write xls and readfile give me the file.

**Second Way**

I generating xls with putting

```
 header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');     // HTTP/1.1
    header('Cache-Control: pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0');    // HTTP/1.1
    header ("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: none');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"test.xls\""); 
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

foreach ()

{

echo contents to the file

}
```

Is there any difference between these 2 ways of generating file.

What is difference.

Comment: what is the second way? It doesn't seem to output any data. and what's the use of readfile in the first one?

Comment: You are not really generating a file in the second example, are you?

Comment: Sorry .. Now i edit the code , after putting header in a foreach loop i write the contents to file

Comment: @zod what do you want to know? Do you want to know what the headers are good for?

Comment: the thing i want to know is little different from quetion :(. i create .xls using fopen. How can i write contents to that .xls to keep it as a pure xls file. If i write tab seperated value, it works fine in 2003 , but showing unsupported type alert message in 2007. So can i write contents to an .xls file using PHP without using classes like PHExcel.

Comment: onlty thing i could imagine is not to write a .xls but rather to write a csv file wich excel can handle in any version you like

Comment: Me too think the same way ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach creates the file inside the server filesystem, then serves it through the browser. The file stays there (unless you have extra code to delete it afterwards).

Your second approach does not seem to create an actual file inside the filesystem, it generates data on the fly - and the browser then saves it to a file.

Is that what you were asking?

Comment: yes this is what i am asking. But am asking is there any difference in format or anything internally to thefile genrated by two ways or they will be identical?

Comment: No. The code you provided in the question does not affect the data that you are creating - the difference is merely in how you serve the data. If you are getting different results, then the bug is elsewhere - in the code you are not showing.